# How to check the MSVC library type?

Tags: visual-c++

There are 2 types of library (static/import). How can I get its type other than the name (the type information could be included in the file name such as libcmt.lib, but this could not be the case for customer library).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a copy of the Microsoft document specifing formats for both static and import .lib files:

http://kishorekumar.net/pecoff_v8.1.htm

Another approach might be to take a couple of libraries, look at the header bytes with "dumpbin" and your favorite hex editor.  It should be pretty easy to identify a .lib file from the "magic numbers" in the header.